# Paypal Direct Payments but update my IPN.php?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Paypal Noob here so be expecting a few questions. Is it possible to send a Paypal payment directly to a user but update my IPN to update the payment status? If yes how can I achieve this?

I need to send the ID of the item and the user ID back to my IPN.php and update my database.

**edit:**
How can I update my database if the person receiving the payment doesn’t not have a IPN?
EG, UserA makes a payment directly to UserB paypal account. How can I update my database?

Im testing this code:

```
    // Prepare GET data
    $query = array();
    $query['notify_url'] = 'test.com/ipn.php'; //is this be the IPN URL Paypal POSTs to?
    $query['cmd'] = '_xclick';
    $query['business'] = 'pay@thisuser.com';
    $query['item_name'] = 'Item Name';
    $query['amount'] = $amount; 
    $query['item_number'] = $id; // The group ID  
    $query['payer_id'] = $people_id; // The joiners ID          

    // Prepare query string
    $query_string = http_build_query($query);

    header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $query_string);
```

Is notify_url the address paypal will post back to my webserver so I can update the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Every payment in paypal sends the IPN.

You can send extra variables(i.e. user ID) as custom variable which you can get in IPN.php

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to describe is userA makes a payment to userB via my website but it updates my database, Does userB need a IPN url programmed?

Comment: You can set one IPN url in paypal.

Answer (score 0):

IPN is only for the sender/seller. Only seller needs to use the IPN listener code. Once you receive IPN , you can do whatever you want with it.(update your DB)

If you want to send e-mail notification to your buyer, you can do so in your IPN listener code.(for eg :use the [mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function)

`Does userB need a IPN url programmed?` 
No